# Application of Helmholtz equation

Tags: waves, computational-physics, differential-equations

I have the Helmholtz equation

$$\nabla^2f = -k^2f $$

I am trying to solve it as a second order differential equation using a numerical method.

However, I am unable to find an application of it, other than its special case as the Laplace equation. Could someone tell me another area where I can use the above equation.

Comment: Doesn't Helmholtz arise when solving separable wave equations?

Comment: @KyleKanos could you elaborate a bit about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the [general wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation),
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=\alpha\nabla^2u$$
If you assume that the [solution is separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_partial_differential_equation), $u\left(x,\,t\right)=U(x)\cdot T(t)$, then you end up with,
$$
\frac{1}{T(t)}\,\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial t^2}=\frac{1}{U(x)}\alpha \nabla^2 U
$$
Since these two equations are equal to each other, then we can say,
$$
\frac{1}{T}\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial t^2}=-k^2=\frac{\alpha}{U}\nabla^2U
$$
The right two terms are then the Helmholtz equation:
$$-k^2U=\alpha\nabla^2U\Rightarrow\left(\nabla^2+k^2\right)U=0$$
(where we absorbed the $\alpha$ into $k$ in the right side).

Thus, basically any wave equation with homogeneous initial conditions should end up as a Helmholtz equation due to separability (and probably also due to the superposition principle).