# Mathematical definition of ray

Tags: optics, maxwell-equations, geometric-optics

I have just begun studying geometrical optics, and there is something mysterious about it.

What I want to know is how to derive the definition of ray from Maxwell's equation.

In vacuum, electromagnetic wave equation as follows.

$ \triangledown E^2 - {1 \over c_0^2}{\partial^2 E \over \partial t^2} = 0$ (where E = electric field, t = time, $c_0$ = speed of light in vacuum)

and definition of ray as follows.

$ \triangledown E^2 + k^2E = 0$ (where $k$ is a wave number.)

I don't know how the equation above is transformed into the equation below.

If anyone knows how the equation below is derived from the equation above,

please give some tips.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question is perfectly clear.

Comment: I’m really grateful.

Comment: I covered a brief outline of the Helmholtz equation derivation in [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/697569/25301).

Comment: Thanks to you, I got a hint and figured out how to induce a formula Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply separation of variables to the wave equation via the assumption:
$$\vec E(\vec r,t)=\vec E(\vec r)e^{-i\omega t},\;\;\text{(monochromatic radiation)}$$
then substitution into the wave equation gives:
$$e^{-i\omega t}\{\nabla^2\vec E(\vec r)+\omega^2\epsilon\mu\vec E(\vec r)\}=0.$$
From which, the Helmholtz equation follows by cancellation of the oscillatory factor:
$$\nabla^2\vec E(\vec r)+\omega^2\epsilon\mu\vec E(\vec r)=0.$$
You do not have to assume that the radiation is monochromatic (all the waves at one frequency), it is enough for the equation to be merely separable,
$$\vec E(\vec r,t)=\vec E(\vec r)\Phi(t).$$ However, whenever the monochromatic case is applicable (as is often the case), the above derivation furnishes you with the necessary factors of $\omega$.